# Inductor for LM2575

Tags: eaglecad, power-supply, components, power

Can anyone suggest a 330uH inductor and associated Eagle .lbr for use with an LM2575?

I've been looking all day for this! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On-Semi is a second source for this part. There may be some additional
information at http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=LM2575

Are you choosing the LM2575 because you want a through hole buck converter? 
If you can do SMD parts there are parts that offer much better performance.
A higher frequency part will let you use much smaller capacitors and inductors.

TI also makes some buck converter modules (TH packages) that are very inexpensive. Checkout
the PTR and PTN series devices.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advice... I'm looking at the LM2575 because it seemed like a simple enough switching regulator.  If you have a better suggestion for a more efficient 12 -> 5v 1A switching regulator I'd love to hear it.

Comment: The issue is what kind of parts to you want to solder? TI has a nice TH module PTN78000W 7V-36V Adjustable output voltage 1.5A which is around $12. All you need is a couple of caps and a resistor. A couple of ICs you could check are the TI TPS54232D, LT1936, LT1767. I would do a search at TI and at Linear Technology.

Comment: Excellent, I've gone for the PTH08080W... similar projects to mine seem to be using it, and it gives me lots to play with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the [datasheet](http://www.national.com/mpf/LM/LM2575.html#Overview) suggests a [Pulse PE-52627](http://www.mouser.com/search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=96C2vqMyhuqmP4c6N2Ancw%3D%3D) for most designs. If you use National's Webench, and put in your exact design requirements (input/output voltage, current) then I'm pretty sure it will suggest a part number.